# Create Chain Relationships from csv in cypher(neo4j)

Tags: csv, neo4j, cypher

i have a csv file like this from a relational schema

`busId | stopId
1  |1
1  |2
1  |3
2  |2
2  |5
2  |3`

i have previously imported the Bus and Stop Nodes. now i want to create relationships between those stop nodes like this

```
(Stop1)-[:Next]->(Stop2)-[:Next]->(Stop3)
(Stop2)-[:Next]->(Stop5)-[:Next]->(Stop3)
```

any idea how i can achive this from cypher?

thanx in advance

Comment: I'm not 100% sure of this answer, but see this related question.  It will give you an idea of how to load this data, and issues you may run into in trying to do that.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28792713/issues-loading-data-patterns-from-csv/28795139#28795139

Comment: Are there already relationships between Bus nodes and Stop nodes? And if so, is there some property on those relationships, either timestamps or ascending numerical values or something that can be ordered?